# a way to support totally different url structure

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, urls, rewrite-rules, rewrite-tag

I need to support permalink URL structure like:

```
http://example.com/adult-course/newyork/language-course/english/standard
http://example.com/adult-course/newyork/language-course/english/profi
http://example.com/adult-course/chicago/language-course/english/standard
http://example.com/child-course/chicago/language-course/german/standard
http://example.com/child-course/chicago/school-course/math/standard
```

(city, course type etc. are taxonomies).

If there would be unique slug within these links I could do something like:

```
add_action('init', 'custom_permastruct_rewrite');
function custom_permastruct_rewrite() {
  $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("%some_slug%", '([^/]+)', "name=");
  $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('course_link', '/adult-course/newyork/language-course/english/%some_slug%', false);
}
```

...but there's not :(

On the other hand I can also do something like:

```
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
    add_rewrite_rule( --preg_expression_here--, --redirect_address_here, 'top');
}
```

...which works, but the address is "rewritten" as the function name says and I get redirected from the original URL so: http://example.com/adult-course/newyork/language-course/english/standard to something like for instance http://example.com/course/my-unique-slug

Comment: Rewriting and redirecting are not the same thing. If your rewrite rule results in a redirection, it's not working.

Comment: I know that they are different things and that now it is not working. I'm asking if it can be done in Wordpress without rewriting the Wordpress core, and if someone could suggest some solution :)

Comment: Sure you can do it without rewriting core. All that needs to be done - is correctly written rewrite rule.

Comment: add_rewrite_rule will redirect me to the default URL or is there a way to prevent it? $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct on the other hand needs a unique name= and I would need to look up the post by type && city && course-leve etc. and from my research it looks like it cannot be done using add_permastruct + add_rewrite_tag